# Angular 2 template wide javascript

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services

I built an Angular 2 application that has some template javascript (for example opening / making the menu smaller, closes content panels). I was wondering what would be the best way to store this type of "template wide" javascript?

For example:

```
// Panel toolbox
$(function () {
    $('.collapse-link').on('click', function() {
        var $BOX_PANEL = $(this).closest('.x_panel'),
            $ICON = $(this).find('i'),
            $BOX_CONTENT = $BOX_PANEL.find('.x_content');

        // fix for some div with hardcoded fix class
        if ($BOX_PANEL.attr('style')) {
            $BOX_CONTENT.slideToggle(200, function(){
                $BOX_PANEL.removeAttr('style');
            });
        } else {
            $BOX_CONTENT.slideToggle(200);
            $BOX_PANEL.css('height', 'auto');
        }

        $ICON.toggleClass('fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down');
    });

    $('.close-link').click(function () {
        var $BOX_PANEL = $(this).closest('.x_panel');

        $BOX_PANEL.remove();
    });
});
```

Is some Javascript that I would need to use on each component that has a content panel. Would I have to import the in each component? Or could I make a custom directive and import that in my root component?

**Edit:** ok, it is clear to me that I shouldn't use this jquery but that I shoud just write the code in typescript. My question still remains:

**should I import my often used function in each component, or is it possible to define a function in a parent component, and use it in the child components?**

Comment: Angular2 template engine will not execute `<script>` due to security reasons. You'll have some hard time trying to figure out the connection between your components and that piece of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put  your code in the  `ngAfterViewInit()` lifecycle method
 in your **root component**. Maybe you need to access the elements with [ElementRef](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html).

*But i don't think its a good idea to manipulate the dom with jquery.*